# Lengthen the square of the event fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using the fullCalendar library but when I put an event on a certain schedule, but without the end of that event, I would like it to be placed in the square of the hour, and that it does not get longer. Here I leave you as the event appears

[image]

I would like you to see me like this:

[image]

Comment: Have a look at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/defaultTimedEventDuration

Comment: Thank you very much